# Not able to See HTML result in Azure release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a azure release pipeline in that I have a task publish my html report.

That step executed but after release run i do not see that html

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For build pipeline:

You can check the Html result in the "HTML Viewer" tap of the run.

Example:
[image]

But for the release pipeline, it seems there is no way to display the tap. Please check the same issue raised before for [the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakubRumpca.azure-pipelines-html-report&ssr=false#overview) :   [I cant see the HTML tab after successfull release](https://github.com/JakubRumpca/azure-pipeline-html-report/issues/7).

Comment: ok.SO do we have some other extension that do same in release piepline

Comment: I didn't find an extension that do the same in the release pipeline. I only found this feature request ticket https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a/491426  and you can vote on it.